# Type of returned value in SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, return-type

Is it possible to know the type of the return values in a SPARQL query?
For example, is there a function to define the type of ?x ?price ?p
in the following query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?price ?p
                    WHERE {
                        ?x a :Product .
                        ?x :price ?price .
                        ?x ?p ?o .
                    }
```

I want to know that

```
typeOf(x) = resource
typeOf(?p) = property
typeOf(?price) = property target etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### datatype(?x)

The datatype function will tell you whether a result is a resource or a literal and in the latter case tell you which datatype it has exactly.

For example, the following query on `https://dbpedia.org/sparql`...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?code ?p datatype(?x) datatype(?code) datatype(?p)
                    WHERE {
                        ?x a dbo:City.
                        ?x dbo:areaCode ?code .
                        ?x ?p ?o .
                    } limit 1
```

[...will return](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fx+%3Fcode+%3Fp+datatype%28%3Fx%29+datatype%28%3Fcode%29+datatype%28%3Fp%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fx+a+dbo%3ACity.%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fx+dbo%3AareaCode+%3Fcode+.%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fx+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++%7D+limit+1&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on):

| x | code | p | callret-3 | callret-4 | callret-5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aconchi | "+52 623" | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI |

However this will not differentiate between "resource" and "property" because a resource may be a property. What you probably mean is "individual" and "property" but even a property can be treated as an individual, for example in the triple `rdfs:label rdfs:label "label"`.

However you can always query the rdf:type of a resource, which may give you rdf:Property, owl:DatatypeProperty or owl:ObjectProperty.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. I guess that I can neither determine if a returned property of a class is inverse or not?

Comment: @GeorgePerid: What do you mean with "if a returned property of a class is inverse"?

Comment: @Kontrad 
For example, if we had the properties of 'teaches', 'semester' as follows:
<Teacher, teaches, Course>
<Course, ofSemester, Semester>

as inverse property of class Course 
I mean the property of 'teaches' 
(since this property 'points to' Course)

Comment: @GeorgePerid: I think you mean the domain and range of a property, which you can specify and query using RDFS as rdfs:domain and rdfs:range, see https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_properties.